# Angular 2 errors while downloading

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular 2 each time I try to download it using the npm throws some errors 
Is that angular 2 still beta means that it's not ready for production?

Comment: What's the error message? If you have a poor internet connection or your system set up poorly, how is that related to Angular 2 being ready for production?

Comment: post the error you got during installation.

Comment: I guess you missed peerDependencies of angular2.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this combination:

```
 "dependencies": {
          "@ngrx/store": "1.3.3",
          "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.12",
          "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
          "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
          "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
          "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
          "zone.js": "0.6.6"
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly create `package.json` (ignore if you have already) by `npm init` in empty folder via terminal.
- Update you package.json dependency list file with this code -

> "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.14",
>
> "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
>
> "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
>
> "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
>
> "zone.js": "0.6.6"

- Than run the command `npm install`

this will create folder named `node modules` in your project

for more info see here https://angular.io/guide/quickstart